# Angular 4 show list data from firebase to md-table

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to create a table which will load data from firebase and show in the created table.

Here is my component HTML

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div>Dealers</div>
    <div>
        <md-form-field floatPlaceholder="never">
            <input mdInput #filter placeholder="Filter dealer">
        </md-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <ng-container mdColumnDef="userId">
                <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
                <md-cell *mdCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container mdColumnDef="email">
                <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> Email-Id </md-header-cell>
                <md-cell *mdCellDef="let row"> {{row.email}} </md-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <md-header-row *mdHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
            <md-row *mdRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
        </md-table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit,ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FirebaseApisService } from '../firebase-apis/firebase-apis.service';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-season',
  templateUrl: './season.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./season.component.css']
})
export class SeasonComponent implements OnInit {
 // season: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'mobile', 'email'];
  dataSource: DataSourceDealers | null;
  @ViewChild('filter') filter: ElementRef;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private fireApi: FirebaseApisService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.subscribe((param)=>{
      this.dataSource = new DataSourceDealers(this.fireApi,param);
      Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .debounceTime(150)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(() => {
        if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
        this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
      });
    }) 
  }

}
export class DataSourceDealers extends DataSource<any> {
  _filterChange = new BehaviorSubject('');
  get filter(): string { return this._filterChange.value; }
  set filter(filter: string) { this._filterChange.next(filter); }
    season: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    input: Observable<any>;
    dealers: any[] = [];
    constructor(private fireApi: FirebaseApisService,param) {
      super();
    }
    connect(): Observable<any> {
      this.season = this.fireApi.getDealers('/Dealers')
      this.season.subscribe(dealer => {
        this.dealers = dealer}
      );
// what to return here

    }
    disconnect() {}
  }
```

I am not getting what to return so that It will show data from firebase list and show data and also able to search based on the name of the dealer.

How can I show firebase list data in material m-table